# Fancy box confirm dialog

Tags: jquery, html

Am building a confirm dialog with fancybox.
This is the module handling the creating of the dialog

```
var Utility = (function() {
function confirm_dialog(title,msg,callback)
        {
            var ret;
            $.fancybox('<div class="confirm-dialog"></div>',
            {
                'width':400,
                'height':250,
                'modal' : true,
                'transitionIn' : 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'speedIn' : 300,
                'speedOut' : 300,
                'autoScale' : false,
                'scrolling' : 'no',
                'overlayShow' : true,
                'overlayOpacity' : 0.3,
                'overlayColor' : '#666',
                'padding':10,
                'onComplete':function() {
                    $('.okBtn').click(function(){
                            ret = true;
                            $.fancybox.close();
                        })
                    $('.cancelBtn').click(function() {
                        ret = false;
                        $.fancybox.close();
                    })
                },
                'onClosed':function() {
                    callback.call(this,ret);
                }
            });
            var html = '<div class="confirm-box">'+
                       '<div class="confirm-title">'+title+'</div>'+
                       '<div class="confirm-msg">'+msg+'</div>'+
                       '<div class="confirm-buttons">'+
                       '<button class="okBtn">Ok</button>'+
                       '<button class="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>'+
                       '</div>'+
                       '</div>';
            $('.confirm-dialog').append(html);
        }
        return {  dialog : confirm_dialog }
})();
```

This is how am implementing my confirm dialog

```
Utility.dialog('Delete Pheed','Are sure you want to delete this pheed ?',
                        alert('hi'));
```

the fancy box show up but the dialog does not show, what am i doin wrong

Answer (score 0):

The fancy box [api](http://fancybox.net/api) has the `content` option which can include html content. Instead of generating the content of the `confirm-dialog` div you could include it directly.

EDIT: Please make sure that you have fancybox version 1.3+ for `content` to work.

I am not sure about this, and please correct me if I am wrong, the problem with this approach is that the `confirm-dialog` div might not be found in the dom elements after the the `fancybox` function is called.

Comment: I'll try using the content option